# Horizontal Overflow/Text Inside Span nested inside Div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to build a type of ticketing system, where each ticket is a `div` and has other, nested `div`s inside of it to better accommodate content. Aside from images and other types of media, it has a plain text area where a description of the ticket will go.

Everything works as it should, but when I print the description, the text continues horizontally, never vertically. This in turn produces a horizontal overflow and the `div` which contains that text apparently extends beyond the 100% width (which I understand fills its parents div width) I had assigned to it.

The text is inside a `span` tag, which is in turn inside the description `div`. I'm fetching that text from a JSON I receive client side, and I'm just concatenating, i.e. :

`var description = receivedJson.description;`

`var desDiv = '<div class="description"><span>'+description+'</span></div>';`

I think part of the problem is I'm concatenating all of it in a single line. Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C5T7N/), but again, since it's not dynamically substituting text, it kinda works and doesn't correctly reproduce the problem.

This is what's actually happening.:
[image: This]

I'm getting both scrollbars, when I only want the vertical one - if-and-only-if it's needed. Even if no text is present, I get scrollbars (probably cause of the padding I have on that `span` tag, but then how do I get spacing between the text and the div?).

How can I get the text to display vertically and only get a vertical scrollbar when the text exceeds the `div`'s height?

Comment: What's your question? You want the text to wrap?

Comment: Have you tried word-wrap on the containing element?

Comment: use word-wrap for breaking the text

Comment: Did `word-wrap:break-word` and it worked. Still getting horizontal scrollbar due to padding though and the right border on the containing div doesn't show. Workaround?

Answer (score 0):

```
.c span {
display: inline-block;
height: 100%;
padding: 1em 2em;
background-color: red;
}
```

remove width:100% . this should work fine :)